# If I look at my own private parts, will my wudu/ghusl be broken?

Tags: wudu, ghusl

I once perfomed ghusl while taking a shower. After I came out of the shower, when I was putting my clothes back on, I accidentally looked at my private part. I thought my wudu/ghusl was broken, so I went back into the shower and repeated my ghusl. Was that necessary? I know that touching you private part breaks wudu. But what about looking at it?

Comment: No, looking at the private parts don't break the wudu.

Comment: What if I look at my private part intentionally?

Comment: Why do you think this could break your wudu or ghusl?

Comment: Why not? I know touching the private part breaks wudu. So I just happened to guess that looking at it would probably have the same effect.

Comment: I am not saying looking at your private parts break your wudu, but why make ghusl again when you just could do wudu?

Comment: I was in a state of sexual impurity

Comment: I think there are posts asking for conditiond when ghusl and or wudu is needed looking at your private parts might be considered as something one should avoid but without a sexual arousal there's no need neither for wudu nor ghusl.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the private parts does not break the Wudhzu.

Comment: This answer needs more meat, please elaborate a good answer (see [answer]).